# Thread 1 exc_bad_access Error

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am developing an iOS app and working with google maps. Drawing lines on a map, add the coordinates in a mutableArray, save those coordinate in NSUSERDEFAULT works perfectly. But when getting the data back from NSUSERDEFAULT and showing the coordinates on google maps does not work. In GMSMutablePath, the app crashes with the following error message : `exec_bad_access (code=1,address=0*4)`. **Any idea why?**

**Here is the related code:**
   Getting Data

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *coordinateArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"numberArray"];
NSLog(@"%@",coordinateArray

for (int i = 0; i < [coordinateArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dic = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *lat = [dic valueForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString *longitude = [dic valueForKey:@"long"];
    _valuePoints.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
    _valuePoints.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    GMSMutablePath *path = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] initWithPath:self.polyline.path];
    [path addCoordinate:_valuePoints];
    self.polyline.path = path;
}
```

Comment: Please show the where you are reading from `NSUserDeafults`.  It is not clear from what you've shared where the crash is occuring.

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *coordinateArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"numberArray"];
    NSLog(@"%@",coordinateArray);

Comment: Is your app trying to access "numberArray" before its been saved?  Why type of object is the array holding?  Just a basic `NSDictionary`?  Or is it some other custom object?  You can use `[defaults arrayForKey:]` to clarify your code intention as well.